# laravel variable prints 1 instead of string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

When printing a model's variable into an input value
this code:

```
value="{{ old('name',  $event->name or null) }}"
```

prints: **1**

and this code:

```
value="{{ old('name',  isset($evento->name) ? $evento->name : null) }}"
```

prints: "the actual value"

Anyone knows why? The first example is supossed work if I'm reading the docs right.

Comment: In PHP the first example is saying unless the first argument evaluates to `true` then do the second (when the first argument does evaluate to `true`, it just returns `true`). `true`  as a string is represented as `1`. You could do `$event->name ?: null` or if you're using >=PHP7 `$event->name ?? null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a test and try to dump the value that is being returned by `$event->name or null` you can see that it retuns `true`, in your html this translates to `1`.

Your second method can be translated to pseudo code:

```
if (isset(...))
    return name
else
    return null
```

This will actually return the `name` value or `null` value.

Depening on your [PHP (7.0)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce)/[Laravel (5.5)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers) version you can write in two shorter ways.

```
// PHP 7.0
$evento->name ?? null

// Laravel 5.5
optional($evento)->name
```

Comment: I'm guessing I didn't understand the actual functionality for this operator (I'm moving from CodeIgniter to Laravel)
I was expecting it to print the value **or ** print the second argument

Comment: Actually, here says clearly that we shouldn't use it: https://laravel-news.com/blade-templates-null-coalesce-operator
I was just reading older tutorials.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is behaving that way because in your first code, you are basically printing a boolean expression.

```
$event->name or null
```

Will return a boolean, so a 0 or a 1. On the other hand, in your second version of the code, you are using a ternary operator which does the following:

1. Check if $evento->name exits
2. If yes, print $evento->name
3. If no return null

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I arrived here with the exact issue stated in the post title, but my situation was slightly different than that of the OP.

I was updating from legacy Laravel blade code featuring `or` instead of `??`.

Changing `{{ $variable or 'Default Value' }}` to `{{ $variable ?? 'Default Value' }}` worked for me.